# ObjectDataSource binding concerns

Tags: .net, ado.net, objectdatasource

I'm well aware of the general pros (quick, fast, easy, codeless approach; support for paging & sorting) and cons (isolated data logic on presentation side) of ODSs, but I'm wondering about the pros and cons of using *multiple* ObjectDataSource objects on a page and the cost on memory/performance.

I'm currently building a page which has circa forty drop down boxes; the approach with the project is to use ODS for all binding, but I'm conscious of the cost in doing so in this scenario. Am I better off using standard ADO.NET approach for increased memory/performance reasons? And what are the benefits to both approaches with such a volume of data?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you think that performance is such a major concern for your application, you should probably create both possible solutions, test them and choose the one that performs best. This is certainly a lot of additional work for you, but I think it’s the only way how to really decide which approach is better.

So do it if you think it’s worth it or choose the approach that seems easier and more intuitive to you. After the test you might even find out that the two approaches differ (in performance) just marginally or that one processes faster just one specific type (or amount) of data.

Comment: Thanks Machta, that's a good approach I think. I will certainly do some prototyping of the different scenarios and take it from there.